# How can I ensure memory safety in this shared library when Marshal.FreeHGlobal() fails?

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management

I have a C# script used in a Unity project. The C# script imports a Dll which is a function I wrote in C++. In my C# script I want to call the C++ function, do something with the data returned from the function, then free any memory. I'm confused because I thought Marshal.FreeHGlobal() would be the right function to call, but it leads to an error in practice. I don't think I should free the memory in the C++ function, because I still need to use the data when that function returns in C#. Here is the two functions I'm using along with a comment where I thought Marshal.FreeHGlobal() would belong

C#

```
  void OnMessage(Message message) {
    byte[] byteArray =
        message.payload.ToByteArray();
    int currentFrameWidth = (int)message.payload.Width;
    int currentFrameHeight = (int)message.payload.Height;
    int decodedFrameLength;
    IntPtr output = MyCppFunction(
        byteArray, byteArray.Length, out decodedFrameLength);

    byte[] resultByteArray = new byte[decodedFrameLength];
    Marshal.Copy(output, resultByteArray, 0, decodedFrameLength);
    
    // Attempting to call this causes an error "free(): invalid pointer"
    // Marshal.FreeHGlobal(output);
    
    Debug.Log("decoded frame length was: " + decodedFrameLength + " and resultByteArray length was: " + resultByteArray.Length);
    if (resultByteArray.Length > 0) {
      //Do stuff with resultByteArray
    }
  }
```

C++

```
  unsigned char* MyCppFunction(const unsigned char* messagePtr,
                                  int messageSize, int* decodedFrameLength) {
  std::vector<uint8_t> decoded_img(33554432);
  int decoded_len = 0;

  decoder_->DecodeFrame(
      reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(messagePtr), messageSize,
      reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(decoded_img.data()), &decoded_len,
      33554432);

  *decodedFrameLength = decoded_len;
  unsigned char* outputData = new unsigned char[decoded_len];
  std::memcpy(outputData, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(decoded_img.data()),
              decoded_len);

  return outputData;
}
```

Comment: You appear to confused by the existence of two different APIs on the C++ side. There is the pair `malloc` / `free`, and there is the pair `new` / `delete`.  Those two don't usually mix... Just pass the pointer back to C++, and delete it there. That works with all types.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on c# understanding what C++'s memory allocation is doing. You need to pass a buffer in from the C# side.

Something like the following in C++

```cpp
void MyCppFunction(
  const unsigned char* messagePtr,
  int messageSize,
  unsigned char* outputData,
  int* decodedFrameLength)
```

The equivalent `DllImport` looks like this:

```cs
[DllImport("libraryname.dll")]
void MyCppFunction(
  byte[] messagePtr,
  int messageSize,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 3)]
  byte[] outputData,
  ref int decodedFrameLength);
```

You then don't need to marshal anything at all, as it's all done automatically.

```cs
void OnMessage(Message message)
{
    byte[] byteArray =
        message.payload.ToByteArray();
    int currentFrameWidth = (int)message.payload.Width;
    int currentFrameHeight = (int)message.payload.Height;
    int decodedFrameLength = 33554432;
    byte[] resultByteArray = new byte[decodedFrameLength];
    IntPtr output = MyCppFunction(
        byteArray, byteArray.Length, buffer, ref decodedFrameLength);
    //
}
```

On a side note, if you *do* want to use `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` you should put it in a `finally`.